# Does the metric induce the topology on $X$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X=\left\{a,b,c\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ and on $X$ the product topology $\tau$, where on $\left\{a,b,c\right\}$ we consider the discrete topology.

On $X$, consider the metric
$$
d(x,y)=\begin{cases}2^{-k}\text{ with }k\text{ maximal s.t. }x_{[-k,k]}=y_{[-k,k]}, & x\neq y, x_0=y_0\\2, & x\neq y, x_0\neq y_0\\0, & x=y\end{cases}
$$

> > My question is whether the metric $d$ induces the product topology $\tau$ on $X$.

Comment: What do you think? What do basic open sets in the product topology look like? What do the open balls look like?

Comment: I think it induces the product topology since so-called cylinder sets $[y_m\ldots y_n]:=\left\{x\in X: x_j=y_j\forall~m\leq j\leq n\right\}$ form a base of the product topology. Hence it suffices to show that for each element in such a cylinder set we find an open ball with positive radius which lies inside the cylinder set. So let $x\in [y_m\ldots y_n]$. I guess we then can choose any centered  cylinder set $[y_{-p}\ldots y_p]$ with $p>\max(m,n)$  and coinciding on the position $m$ to $n$ as open ball lying in $[y_m\ldots y_n]$, $d(x,y)\leq 2^{-\max(m,n)}$ for each $y\in [x_{-p}\ldots x_p]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not checked if $d(x,y)$ is indeed a metric, but to show that $d$ induces the product topology $\tau$ on $X$ it is enough to show that for every non-empty open $V\in \tau$ there is a basic ball $B(a,r)\subseteq V$, and that for every ball $B(a,r)$ there is an open $V\neq \emptyset$ such that $V\subseteq B(a,r)$.

- Suppose $V$ is a basic open in the product topology of $X$, then it
  has the form $V=\prod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}X_i$ where $X_i=\{a,b,c\}$
  except for possibly finitely many indices $i_1,\ldots,i_n$, for which
  $X_{i_j}$ could be any subset of $\{a,b,c\}$. Pick an arbitrary
  element $(a_{i_1},\ldots,a_{i_n})\in X_{i_1}\times \cdots \times
     X_{i_n}$ and choose $k_0\in\mathbb{Z}$ large enough such that
  $i_1,\ldots,i_n\in [-k_0,k_0]$.

  Consider an element $\overline{x}=(x_i:i\in\mathbb{Z})$ of $X$ with
  $x_{i_j}=a_{i_j}$ for $j=1,\ldots,n$. Put $r=2^{-(k_0)}$. We can show
  that $B(\overline{x},r)\subseteq V$.

  If $\overline{y}\in B(\overline{x},r)$, then since
  $d(\overline{x},\overline{y})=2^{-k}<r=2^{-k_0}$ where $k$ is maximal
  such that $\overline{x}_{[-k,k]}=\overline{y}_{[-k,k]}$ we have that
  $x_i=y_i$ for all $i\in [-k,k]$. In particular,
  $y_{i_j}=x_{i_j}=a_{i_j}$ for $j=1,\ldots,n$, and given that
  $a_{i_j}\in X_{i_j}$ for all $j\leq n$, we must have $\overline{y}\in
     \prod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}V_i=V$
- On the other hand, consider the ball let $B(\overline{x},r)$ and
  choose $k_0\in\mathbb{Z}$ large enough such that $2^{-k_0}<r$. Then the
  basic open $$V=\prod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}Y_i \hspace{1cm}\text{ with
     }Y_i=\begin{cases}\{x_i\} &\text{if $i\in [-k,k]$}\\ \{a,b,c\}
     &\text{if $i\not\in [-k,k]$}\end{cases}$$ satisfies that $V\subseteq
     B(a,r)$ because if $\overline{y}\in V$, then $\max\{k:
     x_{[-k,k]}=y_{[-k,k]}\}\geq k_0$ and so
  $d(\overline{x},\overline{y})\leq 2^{k_0}<r$, which implies
  that $\overline{y}\in B(\overline{x},r)$.

Comment: Now I wonder if d really is a metric. :D

Comment: I think it is: the only problem seems to be the triangle inequality, but notice that if $d(\overline{x},\overline{y})=2^{-k}$ and $d(\overline{y},\overline{z})=2^{-ell}$, then $\overline{x}$ and $\overline{z}$ must be equal at least in the interval $[-\min\{k,\ell\},\min\{k,\ell\}]$. Thus, $d(\overline{x},\overline{z})=2^{-s}\leq 2^{-\min{k,\ell}}$, which is enough for the triangle inequality to hold.

Comment: Why is it enough that $d(\bar{x},\bar{z})\leq 2^{-\min(k,\ell)}$?

Comment: What does the triangle inequality say? notice that $2^{-\min\{k,\ell\}}$ is either $2^{-k}$ or $2^{-ell}$.

Comment: Got it, thanks. So $d$ is a metric and induces the product topology, nice! Thanks.